# Finding all tasks belonging to a POSIX process prior to thread-group introduction

Tags: linux-kernel

The following quote from [POSIX Threads and the Linux Kernel](https://landley.net/kdocs/ols/2002/ols2002-pages-330-337.pdf) describes the state of things prior to thread group introduction in kernel 2.4:

> One of the fundamental barriers to adding POSIX compatibility to Linux
>   has been that Linux had no easy way to group all the tasks together
>   that are part of what POSIX would call a process, and iterate through
>   them. It was possible to find all tasks with the same address space,
>   but only by looking at all tasks in the system. This limited what
>   could be added at the kernel level.

I'm curious why the only option to find all the tasks (that are part of what POSIX would call a process) was to `look at all tasks in the system`?

Why the following logic wouldn't work?
- given a handle to a particular task, find the earliest ancestor having the same address space (the assumption here is that each task has a handle to the task it was cloned from)
- search all the tasks having the same address space under the earliest ancestor subtree (the assumption here is that each task has a handle to all of its cloned tasks)
- search all the tasks having the same address space under `init` subtree (the assumption here is that init's task is a root of task tree)

It looks like a lot of work, but still should be less time-complex than iterating over all the tasks.

Comment: double fork -- child dies, grandchild gets adopted by init.

Comment: @mosvy Oh, right.. thanks! I've edited the question to include this case as well.